# List appearing vertical in Mobile view but Horizontal in Desktop View?

Tags: css

So my issue is that my lists are actually appearing horizontal on a desktop (which is what I want). However; they appear vertical when it comes to the mobile layout, as in the first column appears, then the next column is below that and so on.

Here is the code:

```
<div class=”su-row”><div class=”su-column su-column-size-1-2″><div class=”su-column-inner su- 
clearfix”><div class=”su-box su-box-style-default” style=”border-color:#009906;”><div class=”su-box- 
title” style=”background-color:#00bf08;color:#FFFFFF;”>Pros</div><div class=”su-box-content su- 
clearfix”><div class=”su-list su-list-style-“>

 <i class=”fa fa-check” style=”color:#00bf08″></i> content
 <i class=”fa fa-check” style=”color:#00bf08″></i> content<br /></div></div></div>
 </div></div><div class=”su-column su-column-size-1-2″><div class=”su-column-inner su-clearfix”><div 
 class=”su-box su-box-style-default” style=”border-color:#990008;”><div class=”su-box-title” 
 style=”background-color:#bf000a;color:#FFFFFF;”>Cons</div><div class=”su-box-content su-clearfix”> 
 <div class=”su-list su-list-style-“>

<i class=”fa fa-ban” style=”color:#bf000a”></i> content
</div></div></div>
</div></div></div>
```

I'm actually using a plugin on WordPress called shortcodes ultimate.

Just wondering what css I need to add to one of those classes to resolve this issue and get the table to appear horizontally on a mobile view?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: please try to use CSS Media Query. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp

Comment: Thank you for that. I was aware of such a query. I'm just not sure what css classes to apply it to and such. If anyone could let me know cheers.